# Equality between vectors with same length but different length expression in type

Tags: equality, idris, dependent-type

I'm doing some development in Idris and I've being getting into the following problem. Say we have 3 vectors:

```
xs : Vect len  a
ys : Vect len  a
zs : Vect len' a
```

and say we also have

```
samelen : len = len'
```

Finally, we also have the following equalities:

```
xsys : xs = ys

yszs : ys = zs
```

In the first equality, we have an equality for the type *Vect len a* while in the second for *Vect len' a*. Now we want to establish:

```
xsza : xs = zs
```

I've been having a hard time making this work. In particular, trans needs equality between the same types, but that is not the case here. How can transitivity be used here to achieve xsza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, sure:

```
xszs : {A : Type} -> {len, len' : Nat} ->
       (xs, ys : Vect len A) -> (zs : Vect len' A) ->
       len = len' ->
       xs = ys -> ys = zs ->
       xs = zs
xszs {A} {len} {len'=len} xs ys zs Refl = trans
```

I think it's important to know that this basically *has* to be a function. You cannot use the `sameLen` proof to replace `len` with `len'` in the types of things that are already in scope. That is, if your type signatures were all top level, Idris could never be convinced that `zs : Vect len a`. You have to use an auxiliary function. In the above function, `len'` is matched to `len`, justified by matching the `Refl`, before the `zs` variable is introduced. You might argue that's clearly false, as `zs` comes before the `Refl` argument, but, since Idris is a total language, the compiler is allowed to make life easier for you by implicitly reordering the abstraction and the matching and all that jazz. In effect, right before the `Refl` is matched, before `zs` is introduced, the goal type is `(zs : Vect len' A) -> xs = ys -> ys = zs -> xs = zs`, but the match rewrites that to `(zs : Vect len A) -> ?etc`, and `zs` is introduced with a nicer type.

Do note that the `len = len'` thing is really just not necessary, though. This works:

```
xszs : {A : Type} -> {len, len' : Nat} ->
       (xs, ys : Vect len A) -> (zs : Vect len' A) ->
       xs = ys -> ys = zs -> xs = zs
xszs {A} {len} {len'=len} xs xs xs Refl Refl = Refl
```

Or even

```
xszs : {A : Type} -> {len, len' : Nat} ->
       (xs, ys : Vect len A) -> (zs : Vect len' A) ->
       xs = ys -> ys = zs -> xs = zs
xszs xs ys zs = trans
```